# Trying to remove 1 month from date

Tags: codeigniter

I'm looking at someone elses code. Basically, the code is meant to pull out this months figures, and the previous months figures.

Today, it is showing July as current month, and July as previous month. I suspect because it's working out today is the 31st July, and there isnt a 31st of June.

Below is the code to define previous month - any thoughts?

```
$this->monthPrev    = date('F Y', strtotime('this month -1 month'));
$this->currentMonth = date('F Y', strtotime('this month'));
```

Comment: Which output do you want to expect? please clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get previous month date, try this:

```
echo date('F Y', strtotime(date('F Y')." -1 month"));
```

It will return:

```
June 2019
```

[Example snippet](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ee57a0df408ad38c7eb150784012fc646a54f22)